# Ajax BeginForm target = _self still loads page when finished

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have an Ajax.BeginForm which is used to update some fields. However, after this call finishes, I just want the screen to stay as it is, but it keeps redirecting to the link defined in the BeginForm address.

I've added target = "_self" to no avail, it still keeps moving pages when the function completes.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? (maybe It's a missing javascript file or something?)

My HTML looks like this:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "Extraction", null, 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "saveSuccessful", 
    OnFailure = "saveFailed" }, new { target = "_self" }))
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Update(Model model)
{
    // do work here
}
```

I've tried putting a debugger on the saveSuccessful javascript function and can see that this doesn't even get hit as the page already has moved to the page defined on BeginForm.

Comment: Check you have `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` loaded in the order.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, I didn't realise I needed to have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js for the update to work. Adding this has fixed my issue. Thanks again!